# Endless promise loop when trying to fetch CSV data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I know that there are many posts out there about how to use fetch and returning promises from async functions. I've read that you should move the bit of the code that relies on the fetched data/content into the function, but I can't see how that's possible with my setup. So before you close my question as a duplicate, I ask that you read it entirely and try to remember what it was like when you were new to programming and needed some help.

I'm building a React app in which I want to graph a bunch of CSV data depending on user input. I'm trying to fetch the CSV data, pull the two variables out that I want, and then pass it into a VictoryChart. This bit of code successfully fetches the data, converts it to an array separated by the record, and then creates a new array of objects (the data input VictoryChart requires) with only the two fields I want to be my variables:

```
  async function getData(filePath) {
    let dataArray = []
    await fetch(filePath)
      .then(response => {
        return response.text()
      })
      .then(data => CSVToArray(data))
      .then(data => {
        for (let i in data) {
          dataArray.push(
            { DateTime: data[i][0], OATemp: data[i][1]}
          )
        };
        return dataArray
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error))
  }
```

As suggested by several sources, I was going to try to put the VictoryChart into the function after the return dataArray to keep everything that relied on the function in the function, but I don't see how it's possible to control the layout of my page by trying to call a function that then generates a graph. I don't see how you build the DOM with that (am I even using that right?). I'm new to React (and generally an inexperienced programmer) so maybe that's part of the problem.

The only thing that makes sense to me is for the async function to return the data so I can pass it into the VictoryChart. But it seems impossible to extract anything returned from the function out of the promise that it gets wrapped into. I've been told to use `.then` but that just ends up returning a promise. It seems so incestual... To be specific my most recent attempt looks something like this (just using alert to "see" what's happening):

```
  alert(getData('./2021WeatherData.csv').then(data => {return data}))
```

Hopefully, I've just not understood how to properly use `.then` as suggested by others. I have sunk many, many hours into trying dozens of different versions of this and googling every synonym of the problem I can think of. I know I'm missing something so I appreciate any help.

***Providing additional code
Below is what I understand to be the DOM for my React app (please correct me where I'm wrong in my wording etc.). This renders my app to the browser.

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className='Header-button-container'>
        <button onClick={() => alert('Weather')}>
          Weather
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => alert('1st Floor')}>
          1st Floor
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => alert('2nd Floor')}>
          2nd Floor
        </button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <VictoryChart>
      <VictoryLine data={getData('./2021WeatherData.csv').then(data => { return data })} x='DateTime' y='OATemp' />
    </VictoryChart>
  </div>
);
```

To me, this dictates how things show up on the page. I notice that everything here is a tag so I don't understand how I would insert a function where the VictoryLine tag exists. The "data" attribute of the VictoryLine graph requires data as an array of objects and that's what I'm trying to output from my getData function (but it keeps getting wrapped in a darn promise!!). I am able to make it work just fine with a dummy data set I declare within the app, but I'm stuck when trying to fetch data. And since I can't get the data "out" of the function (it seems all that's possible is doing things inside of the function), I'm just stuck and perplexed. The intent here is to be able to click a button and fetch the relevant data to graph.

Comment: You need to `return await fetch...` (or just `return fetch...`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I assume you mean add `return` ahead of `await fetch(filePath)`. I just tried that change alone and then also removed `.then(data => {return data}))` from the end of my alert function call and am still getting [object Promise] as my alert output. If I've misunderstood your suggestion, would you mind elaborating by providing an answer as opposed to a comment here? That way I could accept the answer too assuming I can get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: The return of `getData` is still a Promise. If you want to console.log the result, then just `.then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: Understood. I don’t want to log the result, I want to pass it to a graph as the data input. The alert() is simply for troubleshooting.

Comment: You'll need a state in React which you can set from the asynchronous callback. The state variable will be `undefined` while the data is loading, then hold the data afterwards - and this state variable you can render into the DOM.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I appreciate you checking in. I didn’t get a chance to do any programming yesterday. As evidenced by my skill level, this is just a hobby for me :) But I absolutely can’t stand to not follow up, so I will certainly let you know where this lands. Maybe tonight, maybe this weekend. Sorry to leave your help hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just having trouble getting the CSV result passed along to your graphing function. First, you need to return your value from `getData`; currently it isn't returning anything:

```js
async function getData(filePath) {
  let dataArray = []
  return fetch(filePath)
  ...
}
```

Then you can pass your result in one of two ways:

```js
function theGraphFunction(data) {
  // this graphs your data
}

getData("./path/to/data.csv").then(data => theGraphFunction(data));
```

*or*

```js
(async () => {
  const data = await getData("./path/to/data.csv");
  theGraphFunction(data);
})()
```

Now that you've updated your question to include information about what you're actually trying to do, you could do something like this:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function App() {
  const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData("./path/to/data.csv").then(data => setGraphData(data));
  }, [])

  // only include this if you don't want to render the component
  // until data is loaded
  if(!graphData) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className='Header-button-container'>
          <button onClick={() => alert('Weather')}>
            Weather
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => alert('1st Floor')}>
            1st Floor
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => alert('2nd Floor')}>
            2nd Floor
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <VictoryChart>
        <VictoryLine data={graphData} x='DateTime' y='OATemp' />
      </VictoryChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So I might be thinking about this wrong, but I don't see how passing the data to a function inserts the VictoryChart into the DOM where I want it. I just don't see how I use that function to insert the VictoryChart element into my page. I will throw up some additional code into the original post.

Comment: @SunnyNonsense That seems like a different question: Once I have CSV data, how do I actually graph it? That question isn't really related to promises. Isn't there documentation for how to graph data once you have it, in the library you're using?

Comment: Yes, VictoryChart's accept an array of objects as input. I have no problem getting that to work with dummy data inside the app. I also have no problem fetching my data and transforming it into the exact array of objects I want. The problem I'm having is getting that data "out" of the function to feed to the VictoryChart.

Comment: @SunnyNonsense Whatever you're doing with "VictoryChart's accept an array of objects as input. I have no problem getting that to work with dummy data inside the app.", just put that code in `theGraphFunction`.

Comment: I still don't understand how that function fits into the DOM (still feel like I'm using that wrong). I've tried putting the function call inside of a <div> tag but it just renders as text. If I enclose it in curly braces, it simply disappears. Perhaps I should just bite the bullet and  go through a React tutorial from the beginning. I feel like I'm missing some core concepts here.

Comment: That seems like an important bit of information to leave out of your original question.

Comment: I updated the answer to include some example React code.

Comment: Cully, you are my hero. I did get this to work last night almost immediately with your code. Thanks for providing a working code example instead of just saying "go use useState". And thanks for not giving up on me when we were messing around with promises.